# Could this question please be re-opened? "Are [w] and [j] considered to be consonants?"

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I recently asked the following question: [Are [w] and [j] considered to be consonants?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1878/111)

The question was closed because it was said to be a duplicate of this question: [Are there semi-vowels besides [w] and [j] and which are most common?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/905/111)

I respectfully submit that these two questions are neither duplicates nor near-duplicates and that they require different answers.   The latter question concerns the number and frequency of semivowels.  My question concerns the classification of [w] and [j].

In light of these considerations, I ask that my question be re-opened.

Comment: James, it's important to accept answers in Meta as well! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for asking. <s>Like I said in the comment, it's true that your questions asks something different, but the answer is covered there in my answer also for your question.</s>

Why do you think it's not? You asked about the classification of [w] and [j] and in that question it's explicitly stated that those two are semi-vowels (or semi-consonants, depending on how you want to call them). As far as I know this is the current consensus. Do you have a particular reason for not believing this is the case? That would help me understand your question better.

Upon further thinking, you might be right. I reopened it and I'll see what kind of answers it gets, but you're right: you're not asking for the same thing.